# Capture camera in mathematica On Raspberrypi

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, webcam, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to open and capture a usb webcam with mathematica on raspberrypi 2.
there are some command for example "CurrentImage","ImageCapture",... but no one worked on it.just a serial picamera was work.
do you have any idea ????

Answer (score 1):

A Mathematica function

```
DeviceRead["RaspiCam"]
```

returns an image with default camera settings.

A more powerful and versatile way is to reach out to the RPi's function raspistill:

```
image = Import[ "!raspistill -n -w 600 -h 400 -t 120 -o -", "JPG"];
```

This form gives you access to the cam's exposure options, descriptions of which can be found from the RPi in Terminal with

```
raspistill -?
```

The best source of support is, I think, the Raspberry Pi group on Wolfram Community.

Comment: The above code is applicable to the RPi cam. To get images from a webcam, see https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/webcams/

Comment: Some variation of Import["!fswebcam..." is where I'd start.